# Do we need to digitally sign our application?

Tags: authentication, code-signing, binaries

We have a business-to-consumer (B2C) application (Windows and Macintosh) which is downloadable from the Internet. Is it really important that we will sign our binaries?

Does all the big companies (Skype, Google (Talk), etc..) sign their binaries?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309745/how-important-is-it-to-digitally-sign-our-executables

Comment: Your link is about B2B application, ours is B2C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about Macintosh, but try the article *[Windows try Driver Signing Requirements for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487317)*.

I guess it "looks better" if you sign your application. Most big companies probably sign their binaries but I haven't seen any statistics about it yet. It is purely my observation.